# Как запускать C++ файлы без конфликтов в Clion

Tags: c++, clion

Я скачал Clion недавно. Я создал два .cpp файла с простым кодом (оба кода работают по отдельности верно). Но проблема в том что Clion не может просто так компилировать несколько файлов которые используют `main` (я имею ввиду если написать в обоих файлах `int main(){. . .}` и `int main(){. . .}` то при компиляции любого из этих файлов выдаст ошибку). Как это исправить?

Ошибка:

```
duplicate symbol '_main' in:
    CMakeFiles/CodeForces.dir/158A.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/CodeForces.dir/4A.cpp.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: создавайте отдельные проекты. Они для этого и предназначены. А просто "запустить файл" - так оно не умеет. Хотите "запускать" каждый файл по отдельности - делайте это с консоли.

Comment: Точка входа в приложение `main` в каждом исполняемом файле должна быть только одна. Соответственно вам следует для каждого файла создать цель - исполняемый файл посредством `add_executable`.

Comment: user7860670 как это сделать?

Comment: в своем cmake файле добавляйте еще одну директиву add_executable